# Javascript not working with form input and hiding options

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

so I am trying to do pretty basic form, when when a user selects and option it shows more relative boxes under it. I found some things on here very similar and I can get them to work in jsfiddle but can't get them to work on my page. Was wondering what I am doing wrong. In my head I only have the standard query link and a link to my file. I have also tried just putting the script itself (with proper surrounding code) in the head of my file and it still didn't work right.

My part two question is, I want my javascript to be in an external file. This script looks a little different than the other ones I have used in the past, so I was hoping for some help on making it external friendly.

```
<fieldset>
 <form action="add_card.php" method="post">
 <legend>TEST</legend>
 Parallel: <select name="parallel" id="parallel">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Insert">insert</option>
  <option value="Base">base</option>
  <option value="Award">award</option>    
 </select>
 <div id="insert" style="display:none;">    
   Pack: <input type="string" name="pack" id="pack"></label>
 </div>
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
</fieldset>
```

and right now my external file looks like this

```
$('#parallel').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="Insert"){
    $("#insert").show()
    }
    else{
    $("#insert").hide()
    }
});
```

Here is it working in jsfiddle, i cut out everything that's not very important right now. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/QAaHP/1406/)

//edit had to fix a typo from copying my code from two places.

Comment: Have you tried putting the javascript in `$(document).ready(function(){ //code here });` ?

Comment: I had tried this but it didn't make it work so I took it out, I coupled this with the change below and it works in HTML file. Now to make it external.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the change function instead

```
$('#parallel_test').change(function(){
    if( $(this).val()=="Insert"){
        $("#insert_test").show()
    }
    else{
        $("#insert_test").hide()
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for providing me this, but it still didn't make it work. also, i removed the "_test" parts from my original code. I copied it from a different place where I was testing something.

Comment: Use double equals instead of triple equals

Comment: After some small fixes, this was the main fix. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Try `selectedIndex` and `toggle()`:

```js
$(function() {
  var insert = $('#insert');
  $('#parallel').on('change', function(e) {
    insert.toggle(1 === this.selectedIndex); // option index for `insert`
  });
});
```

```css
#insert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>TEST</legend><!-- moved out off the form tag -->
  <form action="add_card.php" method="post">
    Parallel:
    <select name="parallel" id="parallel">
      <option></option>
      <option value="Insert">insert</option>
      <option value="Base">base</option>
      <option value="Award">award</option>
    </select>
    <br/><!-- added -->
    <div id="insert">
      Pack:
      <input type="string" name="pack" id="pack"><!-- removed </label> -->
    </div>
    <br/><!-- added -->
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

P.S. You have a closing `</label>` tag without opening tag in your post.

Read more about [$.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and [select.selectedIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The script should load after the html is available, so be sure to put the script after `</body>` rather than in `<head>`.

Since you're using jQuery also you could go about a less obtrusive means (i.e. if you have multiple selects or options which could spawn additional children when changed, you could build your selector by using a *class* or *data-* attribute instead).

And lastly be sure to wrap your method in a 'document ready' function, either using the usual means, or jQuery's method:

```
( function( $ )
  {
  }( jQuery )
);
```

All put together you could have something like this:

*html*:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>example</title>
  <!-- Put your css links here -->
</head>
...
<body>
...
<fieldset>
  <form action="add_card.php" method="post">
    <legend>TEST</legend>
    Parallel: 
    <select name="parallel" class="has-extra-hidden-children">
      <option></option>
      <option value="Insert">insert</option>
      <option value="Base">base</option>
      <option value="Award">award</option>    
    </select>
    <div class="is-extra-hidden-child" style="display:none;">    
      Pack: <input type="string" name="pack" id="pack">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</fieldset> 
...
</body>
<!-- link your js script here -->
...
</html>
```

*JavaScript file*:

```
( function( $ )
  {
    $( '.has-extra-hidden-children' ).each
    (
      function()
      {
        var newthis = $( this );
        $( newthis ).on
        (
          'change',
          function()
          {
            if( $( this ).val() === 'Insert' )
            {
              $( this ).find( '.is-extra-hidden-child' ).show();
            }
            else
            {
              $( this ).find( '.is-extra-hidden-child' ).hide();
            }
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }( jQuery )
);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hey thanks! I already had intentions of applying this to classes instead of just IDs but this really inspired me to do it in a better way.